# How to post only the selected value from a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

With the following setup below, all the Nationalities are posted back to the server, I really don't care about the entire list, just the selected value.  How do I modify my code so that only the selected nationality is posted back with the rest of the model?

**Model:**

```
    // SearchCriteria model
public class SearchCriteria()
{
    public SearchCriteria()
    {
        Nationalities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Nationalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Any Nationality", Value = "Any Nationality", Selected = true });
        Nationalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "United States", Value = "United States", Selected = false });
        Nationalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Japanese", Value = "Japanese", Selected = false });
        Nationalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mexican", Value = "Mexican", Selected = false });
        Nationalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Canadidan", Value = "Canadidan", Selected = false });
        Nationalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Chinese", Value = "Chinese", Selected = false });
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Nationalities { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Find(SearchCriteria model)
    {                               
        try
        {
            // find it
            return View(model);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.Label("Name:");
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name);
@Html.Label("Nationality:");
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Nationality, Model.Nationalities);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that populates your Nationalities list?

Comment: It should work fine with your code. The posted value should be in the Nationality property. Did you check there?

Comment: I think you are mistaken.  It's simply impossible for all the nationalities to be posted.  That's just now how HTTP works and not how drop down lists work.  The only way to get all of them is to use a multi-select list and select all of the items, and you are not doing that.

Comment: @Meryovi - yah, but I don't want it to send all the values too... it's not performant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see your problem.  And it's not really a problem per se.  It's a misunderstanding on your part.

The list of nationalities is not posted back to your controller.  They are created by the constructor each time a `SearchCriteria` object is created (including when the model is bound on post).  This is not posted by the client to the server.

While this is extra work that is being done that is not always necessary, it's not really a problem.  The actual posted value should be in the Nationality member of your `SearchCriteria` object.

If you do not want the Nationalities object created each time, then you need to move this to a helper class and call it when you want to populate this data, or you move it out of your class entirely and do it in the controller.  Maybe a better choice would be to move this data to a database.

By the way, you might want to remove that first item and make it your default text instead, which is a parameter of the DropDownList/DropDownListFor object.

Answer (score 2):

`Nationalities` are not posted back, they just being populated on `SearchCriteria` instance creation. You may see what's being poster to the server in Chrome's developer's console or firebug in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Try to **NOT** put your `Nationalities` property as an instance member of your model. Declare the `Nationalities` list as a `static` property in your class on in an other class (like a helper class for instance). The `Nationalities` list is a referential data and it is not very clean (in design terms) that it is part of an instance model.